# VS Code custom folding provider works once then breaks upon file edit

Tags: visual-studio-code, folding

UPDATE:
The breaking of the custom code folding extension appears to be due to it conflicting with the VSCode C# extension. If the C# extension is disabled the custom folding works as expected, but breaks when the C# extension is enabled. I assume I'll have to check on the C# extension forums for any way to work around this issue if there is one.

I am trying to write a VS Code extension for CSharp, that provides custom code folding.
I want it to have the ability to fold/hide any lines of code that are just a '{' or '}' character aside from whitespace. The code I have below works on performing this when a file is first opened, but if you then make any edits to the file the custom folding breaks and seems to partially revert back to CSharp's default folding.

I am wondering what code/config setting I am missing to make it use this custom FoldingRangeProvider even after a file is edited and not just the first time a file is opened.

At the bottom is a link to a repo I made with this extension code. The repo readme has notes on running the extension.

My extensions.ts code is this

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function deactivate() { }

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    vscode.languages.registerFoldingRangeProvider({ scheme: 'file', language: 'csharp' }, new MyFoldingRangeProvider());
}

class MyFoldingRangeProvider implements vscode.FoldingRangeProvider {
    provideFoldingRanges(document: vscode.TextDocument, context: vscode.FoldingContext, token: vscode.CancellationToken): vscode.FoldingRange[] {
        let ranges: vscode.FoldingRange[] = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < document.lineCount; i++) {
            const line = document.lineAt(i).text.trim();
            if (line === "{" || line === "}") {
                ranges.push(new vscode.FoldingRange(i - 1, i, vscode.FoldingRangeKind.Comment));
            }
        }
        return ranges;
    }
}
```

And my package.json code is this

```json
{
    "name": "bracefolding",
    "displayName": "BraceFolding",
    "description": "",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.54.0"
    },
    "categories": [
        "Other"
    ],
    "activationEvents": [
        "onLanguage:csharp"
    ],
    "main": "./out/extension.js",
    "contributes": {
        "languages": [
            {
                "id": "csharp",
                "extensions": [
                    ".cs",
                    "cs"
                ],
                "aliases": [
                    "CSharp",
                    "cs"
                ],
                "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
            }
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile",
        "compile": "tsc -p ./",
        "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./",
        "pretest": "npm run compile && npm run lint",
        "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
        "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/vscode": "^1.54.0",
        "@types/glob": "^7.2.0",
        "@types/mocha": "^9.1.1",
        "@types/node": "16.x",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.30.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.30.0",
        "eslint": "^8.18.0",
        "glob": "^8.0.3",
        "mocha": "^10.0.0",
        "typescript": "^4.7.4",
        "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.1.5"
    }
}
```

The desired behavior is to change a CS code file from looking like this

```cs
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Hello
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!! ");
            
            if ("a" == "b")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("def");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To looking like this after the folding is done. In the code I marked this folding range kind as 'Comment', so on windows the keyboard shortcut to perform this folding is 'Ctrl-K' then 'Ctrl-/'

```cs
namespace HelloWorld
    class Hello
        static void Main(string[] args)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!! ");
            
            if ("a" == "b")
                Console.WriteLine("def");
```

https://github.com/ethanwork/vscode_bracefolding